# Spark -Optimizing long running Job

Tags: apache-spark

we have a spark job that's taking long time to complete, Looked at the spark WebUI and I see lot of shuffling. Couple of things I tried but no luck so far. Increased the sql.shuffle partitions(tried 320,640 and 1600), # of executors (8) and memory (10/12gb) and 4 cores but no significant improvement. Appreciate any guidance on below:

1)when I see the event time line in spark web UI, only one executor is doing most of the processing and rest I don't see any significant activity -  [image: eventtimeline]

2. Metrics, lot of difference for shuffle spill between 75th percentile and max - [image: metrics]

Any pointers on how to investigate further will be of great help! basically looking for documentation on the event timeline as i see single executor is performing bulk of hte work and how to use the metrics to fix the perf issue by adjusting the spark configuration parameters if thats an option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handling Skew data in apache spark production scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017314/handling-skew-data-in-apache-spark-production-scenario)

Comment: All the hallmarks of skew. Which version using?

Comment: Spark version is :2.4.4.4.1.8.19.  Note, its doing a group by and same query if i run in the jupyter notebook, its not showing any slowness.

Comment: What to infer from the event time line as out of 8 executors only one is doing the work ?

Comment: Skew that is what we can infer normally

Comment: Too little information provided

Comment: @thebluephantom , pls let me know what other information  I should include in the post?

Comment: The code...would be a good start...

Comment: I tried spark.sql.adaptive.enabled and spark.memory.fraction =0.8 as  i read that spark.sql.adaptive.enabled will fix the skew issues if any